# Messenger sharing causes "Messenger Extensions unexpected error"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to perform a share with the `beginShareFlow()`function of the facebook MessengerExtensions. However, when performing the call, I get following error message:

```
Messenger Extensions unexpected error.
```

The code for this error is 2018154.

I'm using following code to start a share:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        var message = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(function(share_response) {
            if(share_response.is_sent){
                // close the window w/ requestCloseBrowser().
            }
        }, 
        function(errorCode, errorMessage) {      
            console.log(errorCode+"-"+errorMessage);
        },
        message,
        "current_thread");
    }
}
```

You'll see that I'm using the response of an ajax call to fill up the actual message. This is generated by some backend php code, an example:

```
{"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"generic","sharable":"true","elements":[{"title":"Kerk Poederlee","image_url":"https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo\/static\/images\/raid.jpg","subtitle":"joining at 1535629500","default_action":{"type":"web_url","url":"https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo"},"buttons":[{"type":"web_url","url":"https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo","title":"join raid"}]}]}}}
```

Messenger extension themselves have been loaded correctly, since I'm able to retrieve the PSID with following code:

```
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    MessengerExtensions.getContext('APPID', 
        function success(thread_context){
            fb_user_id = thread_context.psid;
        },
        function error(err){}
    );   
};
```

This error occurs on a web client and on the most recent iOS messenger. When I send the exact same message through the Send API instead of the sharing messenger extensions, it works perfectly. Could somebody help me figure out what's causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake, in the message you can pass a 'sharable' property. I passed the string value "true" to it, but this should be a boolean value.

This is the corrected content:

```
{
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "sharable": true,
            "elements": [{
                "title": "Kerk Poederlee",
                "image_url": "https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo\/static\/images\/raid.jpg",
                "subtitle": "joining at 1535629500",
                "default_action": {
                    "type": "web_url",
                    "url": "https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo"
                },
                "buttons": [{
                    "type": "web_url",
                    "url": "https:\/\/www.wouterh.be\/pogo",
                    "title": "join raid"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```